# python variable type declaration can not find its own class type

Tags: python, types, parameters

I'm training to add type declaration for parameters, because there is no hints after the dote in idea sometimes.

I have such simple test code, where i'm trying to add type for `car_variable` parameter.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0

    def printCarInfo(self, car_variable: Car):
        print(car_variable.speed)
```

But it doesn't work. The word Car is underlined by red color with `Unresolved reference 'Car'` error.

You can see it at the screen:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? what's wrong with `print(self.speed)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0

    def printCarInfo(self, car_variable: "Car"):
        print(car_variable.speed)
```

And I suggest `printCarInfo` should be a static method will be better

Comment: Thank! The answer on you suggestion: it's never mind what the method do. It's only example. The main goal is adding type declaration. Why do I need to use quotes?

Comment: lol,because of pep say so,u could see this `https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references`

Answer (score 0):

the code that you wrote translate to being
car_variable is a variable of type 'car'

you either have to define what is car or maybe use directly like `car_variable: dict()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to reference the class itself like printCarInfo(self, car_variable: "Car"), but you should be able to obtain your goal like this.

```
class Car:
   def __init__(car):
        car.speed = 5
        car.color = 'red'

        car.car_variables =  {   
            'Speed': car.speed,
            'Color': car.color
        }
    

    def printCarInfo(self, car_variable: str):
         print(self.car_variables[car_variable.title()])


c = Car()

c.printCarInfo('Speed')
c.printCarInfo('Color')
```